# UI Controls on HERE's Map Image API?

Tags: user-interface, navigation, here-api

Is it possible to add UI controls (for example, zooming/navigation and pop-up links) to the HERE Map Image API? I've found it available on the [Maps API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/map-controls.html), but I'm trying to see if I can add UI to the [Map Image](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/what-is.html).

UI controls aren't listed in the main features, but I thought I'd ask anyway. Has anyone figured out how to add UI controls to a map image?

Answer (score 0):

Map Image API is used to generate static images, for instance to store in a DB or send by email.
Having zoom/pan graphics generated into the image seems not of much interest.

If you want to display  actionable items (for instance buttons) on top of an image, use div and CSS: you can then overlay div with buttons on top of the div with the image

for instance to add a button hide:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:0
}
#hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index:2
}
```

and then:

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="hide"> <button type="button" onclick="hide();">Hide</button></div>
    <div id='map'></div>
</div>
```